# Add a public key to a jks keystore

Tags: rsa, keystore, keytool, public-key, jks

I have been given a public xml key in the following format:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>MODULUS_VALUE</Modulus>
  <Exponent>EXPONENT_VALUE</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

With this key I need to verify a signed message that I would receive.

I have created a keystore with keytool but I am unable to import this public key there.

Is it possible to add this public key to a blank new jks keystore that I would create?

So far I haven't been able to do exactly that. I would imply that I don't have the private key, I only have the public key in xml format.

Comment: Generally only certificates can be added to establish trust, not a single key. So you may need to spin a certificate around it, but for that you obviously need the private key or a higher level certificate and its private key.

Comment: As the previous comment explains, it is possible to create a keystore entry with a certificate that contains this public key, but it would clumsy and confusing to do so. Why must you use a keystore at all? What code are you using to perform the verification?

Comment: I am using apache camel and its xmlsecurity component. The component accepts a KeySelector implementation. Apache camel has its implementation DefaultKeySelector, which requires a keystore.